# Open pdf page in new tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an Imagebutton inside a nested datalist
I have to open a pdf file when i click the imagebutton. I've tried window.open() method in code behind. But its not working at all.Also tried OnClientClick event too. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "`window.open()` not working at all"? It should work or it should throw an error. What is an error then?

Comment: [try { string[] trim = selectedItems[index].Split('[');
                    DataSet pdfname = ctrl.GetPDFName(trim[0]);
                    string pdf = pdfname.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    if (pdf != "" || pdf != null)
                    {
                       Response.Redirect("~/PDF FILES/" + pdf,false);
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //alert message 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }]

Comment: window.open is not throwing error. But nothing happens when i click the button

Comment: have you tried to set target ?

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I was trying to add this in the 'onclientclick' event. it is working with 'onclick' event now.

    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("MyTestImageButton");
                        imgBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('" + url + "','_blank')");

Answer (score 0):

Just tried and this opens a PDF in new tab.

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/Content/sample.jpg" runat="server" Width="100" 
        OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('/Content/sample.pdf'); return false;" />
```

Comment: I read your comments above and imgBtn.Attributes.Add() seemed to work for you. Do you still have issues? If yes please post your code (datalist aspx and item command event handler). If not then please close the post. It creates confusion.